# Issue with linked lists in c.I dont know why it does not work

Tags: c, linked-list

As you can see in my code I ask the user to input some values (with defensive programming) and then I want to put these values into the list in the correct order. If user's values were `5,4,3` the list should be `[5, 4, 3]`. However this doesn't work... Maybe some help ?

I used double pointer (to call by ref) for the list head and for the pointer which points to the last element `last`. Is it correct?

My compiler says that it is an error in the `insert` function (`*last->next = temp;`). Specifically it says `request from member 'next' in something not a structure or union`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node *Nodeptr;
typedef struct node Node;

void insert(Nodeptr *list, Nodeptr *last, int info) {
    Nodeptr temp;
    temp = (Nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = info;

    if (!(*list)) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        *list = temp;
        *last = temp; // points to last node
    } else {
        *last->next = temp; //points to last node
        *last = temp;
        *last->next = NULL;
    }
}

void print(Nodeptr list) {
    Nodeptr aux;
    aux = list;

    if (!list) {
        puts("Empty!\n");
    } else {
        while (aux != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", aux->data);
            aux = aux->next;
        }
    }
}

main() {
    Nodeptr head = NULL;
    Nodeptr last;
    int i, num;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        do {
            printf("Give number: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);

            if (num < 10 || num > 99) {
                printf("\nWrong!.");
            }
        } while (!(num >= 10 && num <= 99)); 

        insert(&head, &last, num);
    }

    print(head);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct node *Nodeptr;` Typedef pointers are usually considered bad style. Also `Node*` is just shorter then `Nodeptr` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using double pointers is meaningful in this situation.

However, according to the [rules on operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the `->` operator has a higher precedence than the `*` operator. Therefore, you must add parentheses like this:

`(*last)->next=temp;`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with double pointers is fine, but hiding pointers behind typedefs is often considered confusing and error prone. You should probably avoid it and just write `void insert(Node **list, Node **last, int info)`, etc.

The error on `*last->next = temp;` is due to the operator precedence rules: postfix operators such as `->` bind stronger than prefix operators, hence the statement is parsed as `*(last->next) = temp;`. You should instead write `(*last)->next = temp;`.

Regarding the *defensive* programming, it is definitely a good approach. I would suggest you go even further and:

- check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input and discard it with a simple loop.
- check for memory allocation failures
- use a proper prototype for `main` and return 0.
- free the allocated memory

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void insert(Node **head, Node **tail, int info) {
    Node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate Node\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->data = info;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!*head) {
        *head = temp;
    } else {
        (*tail)->next = temp;
    }
    *tail = temp;
}

void print(const Node *list) {
    const Node *aux = list;

    if (!list) {
        printf("Empty!\n");
    } else {
        while (aux != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", aux->data);
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void freelist(Node **list) {
    while (*list) {
        Node *aux = *list;
        *list = aux->next;
        free(aux);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
    int i, c, num, res;

    for (i = 0; i < 3;) {
        printf("Give number: ");
        res = scanf("%d", &num);
        if (res == EOF)
            break;
        if (res == 1) {
            if (num < 10 || num > 99) {
                printf("Invalid value: must be >= 10 and <= 99\n");
            } else {
                insert(&head, &last, num);
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }
    print(head);
    freelist(head);
    getch();
}
```